# How to measure section of environment in unity editor using mouse cursor?

Tags: unity, map-editor

I know in some graphical apps, user can measure object size by dragging the mouse. and the editor draws a line and shows the size. It's a really helpful feature.

is it a feature implemented in unity as a built-in feature or do I have to write an extension for it?

Comment: Typing "unity measure tool" into a search engine turns up lots of threads mentioning that Unity does not have such a tool built-in and offering extensions, assets, and editor scripts to add variations on this functionality. What are you looking for from an answer here that you were not able to find this way?

Comment: @DMGregory its a rudimentary but very useful tool. just was wondering how cant i find it. i just made a simple editor for it.

Comment: Want to post your new tool as an Answer to help others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made a simple Editor overriding  `EditorTool`.

If enabled, when user holds the left shift button, the editor draws a line and shows the size:

```
[EditorTool("Ruler Tool")]
public class RulerTool : EditorTool
{
    VisualElement _toolRootElement;
    bool _downEvent;
    bool _upEvent;

    private Vector3 _startPosition;

    public override void OnActivated()
    {
        _toolRootElement = new VisualElement();
        _toolRootElement.style.width = 200;
        var backgroundColor = EditorGUIUtility.isProSkin ? new Color(0.21f, 0.21f, 0.21f, 0.8f) : new Color(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f);
        _toolRootElement.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        _toolRootElement.style.marginLeft = 10f;
        _toolRootElement.style.marginBottom = 10f;
        _toolRootElement.style.paddingTop = 5f;
        _toolRootElement.style.paddingRight = 5f;
        _toolRootElement.style.paddingLeft = 5f;
        _toolRootElement.style.paddingBottom = 5f;
        var titleLabel = new Label("Ruler Tool");
        titleLabel.style.unityTextAlign = TextAnchor.UpperCenter;


        _toolRootElement.Add(titleLabel);
        var sv = SceneView.lastActiveSceneView;
        sv.rootVisualElement.Add(_toolRootElement);
        sv.rootVisualElement.style.flexDirection = FlexDirection.ColumnReverse;

        SceneView.beforeSceneGui += BeforeSceneGUI;
    }

    public override void OnWillBeDeactivated()
    {
        _toolRootElement?.RemoveFromHierarchy();
        SceneView.beforeSceneGui -= BeforeSceneGUI;
    }

    void BeforeSceneGUI(SceneView sceneView)
    {
        if (!ToolManager.IsActiveTool(this))
            return;


        if (Event.current.type == EventType.KeyDown && Event.current.keyCode == KeyCode.LeftShift)
        {
            if (!_downEvent)
                _startPosition = GetCurrentMousePositionInScene();

            _downEvent = true;
            Event.current.Use();
        }
        else if (Event.current.type == EventType.KeyUp && Event.current.keyCode == KeyCode.LeftShift)
        {
            _downEvent = false;
            Event.current.Use();
        }
    }

    public override void OnToolGUI(EditorWindow window)
    {
        if (!(window is SceneView))
            return;

        if (!ToolManager.IsActiveTool(this))
            return;


        if (_downEvent)
        {
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(_startPosition, GetCurrentMousePositionInScene());
            Handles.Label(GetCurrentMousePositionInScene() + new Vector3(0, 0, 0.7f), distance.ToString());
            Handles.DrawLine(_startPosition, GetCurrentMousePositionInScene());
            Handles.DrawWireDisc(GetCurrentMousePositionInScene(), Vector3.up, 0.5f);
        }

        window.Repaint();
    }

    Vector3 GetCurrentMousePositionInScene()
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = Event.current.mousePosition;
        var placeObject = HandleUtility.PlaceObject(mousePosition, out var newPosition, out var normal);
        return placeObject ? newPosition : HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay(mousePosition).GetPoint(10);
    }
}
```